# How to implement ORACLE to VERTICA replication?

Tags: oracle, replication, vertica

I am in the process of creating an Oracle to Vertica process!
We are looking to create a Vertica DB that will run heavy reports. For now is all cool Vertica is fast space use is great and all well and nice until we get to the main part getting the data from Oracle to Vertica.
OK, initial load is ok, dump to csv from Oracle to Vertica, load times are a joke no problem so far everybody things is bad joke or there's some magic stuff going on! well is Simply Fast.
Bad Part Now -> Databases are up and going ORACLE/VERTICA - and I have data getting altered in ORACLE so I need to replicate my data in VERTICA. What now:
From my tests and from what I can understand about Vertica insert, updates are not to used unless maybe max 20 per sec - so real time replication is out of question.
So I was thinking to read the arch log from oracle and ETL -it to create CSV data with the new data, altered data, deleted values-changed data and then applied it into VERTICA but I can not get a list like this:

Because explicit data change in VERTICA leads to slow performance.

So I am looking for some ideas about how I can solve this issue, knowing I cannot:

1. Alter my ORACLE production structure.
2. Use ORACLE env resources for filtering the data.
3. Cannot use insert, update or delete statements in my VERTICA load process.

Things I depend on:

1. The use of copy command
2. Data consistency
3. A max of 60 min window(every 60 min - new/altered data need to go to VERTICA).

I have seen the Continuent data replication, but it seems that nowbody wants to sell their prod, I cannot get in touch with them.

Comment: if Vertica is used for DW/analytics, this type of work typically involves large, long running ETL processes running periodically (say weekly or maybe each night).  Is the 60 min max requirement yours or management?

Comment: Check out http://www.vertica.com/2012/08/27/load-new-data-and-modify-data-simultaneously/ That might give acceptable performance. I'm on v5, so haven't had the opportunity to use the functionality yet.

Comment: it is a management req :(!! Since is not a hist db , where i can just insert is kind of complicated !!

Answer (score 0):

will loading the whole data to a new table
and then replacing them be acceptable?

```
copy new() ...
-- you can swap tables in one command:
alter table old,new,swap rename to swap,old,new;
truncate new;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract data from Oracle(in .csv format) and load it using Vertica COPY command. Write a simple shell script to automate this process.

I used to use Talend(ETL), but it was very slow then moved to the conventional process and it has really worked for me. Currently processing 18M records, my entire process takes less than 2 min.